# displaying a 12 hours format using php by Row

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to display/echo a 12 hours format of the column modification_out By Row.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){    

  $username=$row['username'];
  $details=$row['details_out'];
  $details=$row['otherout'];
  $modification_out=$row['modification_out'];
```

i got trouble here:

```
echo "  
<tr>
<td><center>".$row['username']."</center></td>
<td><center>".$row['details_out']."</center></td>

<td>date("m/d/y g:i A",".$row['modification_out'].")"</td>

<td><center>".$row['otherout']."</center></td>
</td>
</tr>
";
```

i got this error: `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in`

thanks for all the replies guys, i just figure out the answer.

```
<td>".date("m/d/y g:i A", strtotime($row['modification_out']))."</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What's wrong with your code? It should be working.

Comment: What's the output? the desired output? the content of `$row`?

Comment: it will show the date and time(12 hour format)

Comment: @LeslieTan see my answer it will solve your problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should concatenate your call to `date()` in the same manner - it looks rather odd in your code.

```
echo "  
<tr>
<td><center>".$row['username']."</center></td>
<td><center>".$row['details_out']."</center></td>

<td>".date("m/d/y g:i A", $row['modification_out'])."</td>

<td><center>".$row['otherout']."</center></td>
</td>
</tr>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>".date('m/d/y g:i A',$row['modification_out'])."</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, your syntax is just wrong. See below: (note: This assumes that `$row['modification_out']` is a unix timestamp)

```
echo "  
<tr>
<td><center>".$row['username']."</center></td>
<td><center>".$row['details_out']."</center></td>

<td>".date("m/d/y g:i A", $row['modification_out'])."</td>

<td><center>".$row['otherout']."</center></td>
</td>
</tr>
";
```

Comment: sir thrs a problem. A non well formed numeric value encountered in

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo "  
<tr>
<td><center>".$row['username']."</center></td>
<td><center>".$row['details_out']."</center></td>

<td>date("m/d/y g:i A",".$row['modification_out'].")"</td>

<td><center>".$row['otherout']."</center></td>
</td>
</tr>
";
```

to

```
echo "  
<tr>
<td><center>".$row['username']."</center></td>
<td><center>".$row['details_out']."</center></td>

<td>" . date('m/d/y g:i A',$row['modification_out']) . "</td>

<td><center>".$row['otherout']."</center></td>
</td>
</tr>
";
```

Comment: A non well formed numeric value encountered - error

Comment: What is the type of `$row['modification_out']`? You can find out by using `gettype($row['modification_out']);`

Comment: i just figure it out thanks alot sir. <td>".date("m/d/y g:i A", strtotime($row['modification_out']))."</td>

Answer (score 0):

To solve this `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered`  add `strtotime() function` in $row['modification_out'] to parse an English textual datetime into a Unix timestamp then it will be well-formed date value

```
 echo "  
    <tr>
    <td><center>".$row['username']."</center></td>
    <td><center>".$row['details_out']."</center></td>

    <td>".date("m/d/y g:i A", strtotime($row['modification_out']))."</td>

    <td><center>".$row['otherout']."</center></td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    ";
```